# How to not catch sent email with mail php function?

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I'm using mail() php function, Ubuntu server, and Postfix to send emails and it works great, but all sent emails are goes to the inbox on the server of the user which was mentioned in the **from** field.

The code:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,"-f user@mail.com")
```

I don't want to see all these emails in my inbox mail on the server.

How to make that these emails do not go to the inbox in the server?

Comment: This *might* be a postfix issue, rather than PHP.  That being the case, you might want to raise this question on serverfault.com instead.  (You may get a quicker/better answer.)